# Invalid token while executing xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am getting an invalid token error while trying to select a node using HtmlAgilityPack.

The Xpath I have used is :

```
"//article[contains(@class, 'product-buy')]/div[@class='product-price-wrapper']/div[@class='price']​"
```

Not sure which is the invalid token and how can I solve this

I tried some other xpaths with ' and is working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a character between the last bracket and the closing quote. On this web page it is a Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' ([U+200B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm)). You can tell by trying to arrow through the string in an editor.

Comment: I think that's not the case since simply  xpath div[@class='price']   is working for me in other case

Comment: @JibinMathew - Are you sure? Try deleting the xpath (including the quotes) and try `"//article[contains(@class, 'product-buy')]/div[@class='product-price-wrapper']/div[@class='price']"` (same xpath, but without the zero width space).

Comment: Yes the ZERO WIDTH SPACE was the issue . If we use .Trim() then will it be resolved??

Comment: Sure—if you can't just delete it from your source code. It's not one of the standard characters that Trim, et al., defaults to so you'd have to specify it. Since it's not a visual character, I'd recommend spelling it out in hexadecimal. Example: `.TrimEnd('\u200B')`.